# What is the application of differential equations in electrical circuits?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance, electrical-engineering

I understand the derivation of the resistor, capacitor and inductance but then what is the practical usage of this derivatives?

Comment: The behavior of capacitors and inductors is defined by derivatives or integrals. If you understand that (as you say you do), how do you propose to analyze circuits containing capacitors and inductors without using derivatives?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand the derivation of the resistor, capacitor and inductance

Then you understand that the behavior of a capacitor can defined by a differential equation

$$I(t)=C\frac{dV(t)}{dt}$$

and the behavior of an inductor can be defined by another differential equation

$$V(t)=L\frac{dI(t)}{dt}.$$

> then what is the practical usage of this derivatives?

It's to analyze circuits containing elements whose behavior is defined in terms of differential equations.